# Android APK from appcelerator titanium

Tags: android, titanium, apk, appcelerator

I'm creating an app for Android/iPhone from Titanium.
I publish an APK and it works fine on android 4.2.2 but for some reason I can't install it on older devices.
I use Google android api 2.2 to publish.
this is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <property name="ti.android.runtime">v8</property>
    <sdk-version>3.2.2.GA</sdk-version>
    <analytics>false</analytics>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="tizen">false</target>
        <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
        <target device="iphone">true</target>
        <target device="ipad">false</target>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="blackberry">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <id>lorem Ipsum</id>
    <name>lorem Ipsum</name>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <publisher>lorem Ipsum</publisher>
    <url>lorem Ipsum</url>
    <description>not specified</description>
    <copyright>lorem Ipsum</copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <persistent-wifi>false</persistent-wifi>
    <prerendered-icon>false</prerendered-icon>
    <statusbar-style>default</statusbar-style>
    <statusbar-hidden>false</statusbar-hidden>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>true</navbar-hidden>
    <guid>ed5eb571-eab4-4b3b-8b97-a10b19404318</guid>
    <iphone>
        <orientations device="iphone">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        </orientations>
        <orientations device="ipad">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        </orientations>
    </iphone>
    <modules/>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal"
            android:versionCode="8" android:versionName="2.6">
            <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="19"
                android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
            <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"
                android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
                android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
            <application>
                <activity
                    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                    android:label="lorem Ipsum"
                    android:name=".lorem Ipsum"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
    </android>
</ti:app>
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
The error I'm getting on the devices is: "there is a problem parsing the package". 
Another thing I've noticed is that the apt doesn't seem to have an icon, even though it has one on newer devices.

Comment: Use android:minSdkVersion="8" if you want to run your app for 2.2 os devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the the Titanium compatibility matrix, that version Android doesn't appear to be supported with SDK 3.2.0+, you have 3.2.2.GA showing at the SDK version.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Android

In order to support Android 2.2 (API 8), you'd have to drop the Titanium SDK version down to 3.1.0.